# Soap client request code for Savon 2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, savon

I am working with the Savon gem (version 2.5.1) for creating a Soap request and need if to be formatted as follows:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:soap1="urn:website.co.uk/soap:callreport7">
   <soap:Header>
      <soap1:callcreditheaders>
         <soap1:company>?</soap1:company>
         <soap1:username>?</soap1:username>
         <soap1:password>?</soap1:password>
      </soap1:callcreditheaders>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap1:Test07a>?</soap1:Test07a>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have so far come up with the following:

```
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "CallReport7.wsdl",
  env_namespace: :soap,
  soap_header: { 
    "soap1:callcreditheaders" => {
      'soap1:company' => 'XXXX',
      'soap1:username' => 'XXXX',
      'soap1:password' => 'XXXX'
    }
  }
)
response = client.call(:test07a, message: "Test" )
```

This is returning an error when running in the console of:

```
Savon::SOAPFault: (soap:Server) An internal system error has occurred
```

If I remove the soap_header hash then the test runs and returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
      <Test07aResponse xmlns="website.co.uk/soap:callreport7">
        <TestResult>
          <datetime>2014-06-06T14:18:35.081125+01:00</datetime>
        </TestResult>
      </Test07aResponse>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

The problem is I need the header information and I cannot work out how to format the request for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was with the envelope. I enabled logging in my code so I could see the SOAP produced by Savon and this then allowed me to try the request in SoapUI and do some trial and error testing. Turned out the problem was with the Envelope so the below fixed the problem in my case:

```
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "CallReport7.wsdl",
  pretty_print_xml: true,
  log: true,
  env_namespace: :soap,
  namespaces: {"xmlns:soap" => "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", "xmlns:soap1" => "urn:website.co.uk/soap:callreport7"},
  soap_header: { 
    "soap1:callcreditheaders" => {
      'soap1:company' => 'XXXX',
      'soap1:username' => 'XXXX',
      'soap1:password' => 'XXXX'
    }
  }
)
response = client.call(:test07a, message: "Test" )
```

The logging line of code was the key to solving this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

As usual: First create a valid request using SoapUI. Then build the equivalent (doesn't have to be exact the same) in Savon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The request is valid in SoapUI, the problem I believe is with the formatting of the request in Savon. I'm very new to Savon and trying to understand what the formatting problem is.